# Subprocess as QT widget

Tags: c++, qt, subprocess

I'm developing a simple IDE that has a embed, non-QT OpenGL renderer inside it. To prevent segfault's on the renderer to crash my application I'm willing to create it as a subprocess and somehow attach it as an widget on my QT main window. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [QX11EmbedContainer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qx11embedcontainer.html) in the main process, and then in another process to show your opengl widget.

Comment: By the way: This class has a windows counterpart?

Comment: @scooterman No idea. I don't know is windows support embedding of windows

Answer (score 1):

[QWinHost](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/3/qtwinmigrate/qwinhost.html) and related classes, now found in the [QtSolutions archive](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions), may be of help to you. You will find QWinHost in the [qtwinmigrate plugin](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/trees/master/qtwinmigrate).

Don't be put off by the mention of "MFC support" - you can compile it without the AFXDLL dependencies as specified in the comments in qtwinmigrate.pri.