# Opening another program in PySide (Qt) and displaying inside the original window

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a PySide application. I want to create a widget in which I will display another application (for example an SFML/Irrlicht/Ogre/whatever game, it will be standalone .exe not python script), and the widget will act like a main window for that process. Is this possible?

I don't need any communication with that app, I will do it through sockets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far the easiest approach is just use python's os.spawn, os.system or the subprocess module to start the second process. It will start in its own window that is separate from your application.'

If you really want to embed the subprocess inside your main window, there are a couple of options.
See answers to this question: [Subprocess as QT widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094681/subprocess-as-qt-widget)

Comment: But I want it to be inside my PySide window.

Comment: I see--I misunderstood 'subwindow'. Can you clarify that a bit more in the question? Is this an MDI?

Comment: Yes. Look at this random editor photo: http://forum.computerbild.de/attachments/pc-spiele/far-cry-2-editor-problem-17377d1270644030-hugeforts-1.jpg . It is gui application (managed by wx/qt/winapi/something like that) and it has subwindow when the render is run - and it's a separate process. And tbh I dont know what is MDI, but I hope my question is clarified now.